# É correto usar JS para fazer os efeitos de um HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

O que eu quero saber é se é correto usar JavaScript/JQuery para fazer alguns efeitos de botões e telas, centralizar o conteúdo horizontalmente e fazer certas tarefas que podem ser feitas por CSS.

O design aqui da empresa disse que é melhor usar o JS/JQuery por questão de desempenho e praticidade de manutenção, mas eu estava pesquisando sobre o assunto e parece que se eu usar JS pode ter vários erros de compatibilidade e que é mais difícil corrigir erros pontuais em certas resoluções, dispositivos e versões de software.

Para desenvolver web/mobile de maneira que suporte diversos tamanhos de tela e diferentes navegadores é correto utilizar JavaScript para fazer as animações e correções de layout ou o correto é usar somente CSS/HTML? Por que?

Comment: Incorreto não é, pode ter certeza, pois veja que existem bibliotecas assim para dar compatibilidade para navegadores antigos, o problema é que a manutenção é muito mais complicada e provavelmente mais demorada. Use somente quando necessário. Não vou formular uma resposta, pois é um pouco amplo e a resposta pode soar como "opinião", mas é assim, use "javascript para controlar a posição do layout quando necessário", se puder ser feito com css+html, então evite o js.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation

Comment: Sua pergunta está com dois votos de fechamento como "principalmente baseada em opiniões". Você consegue dar uma melhorada nela para evitar de ser fechada?

Comment: Acho que sim, vou fazer isso.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Ficou melhor? eu não tenho muita criatividade pra dissertar -_-

Comment: Um dos problemas de se utilizar js para animações é o grande volume de gambiarras que é inserido para fazer algo (devido a inexperiência dos programadores) que teria sido facilmente desenvolvido com css. Como o @VictorStafusa colocou, é preciso ter bom-senso para saber em qual situação usar cada tecnologia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que pode ocorrer é de você querer usar recursos do CSS que não existem em todos os navegadores disponíveis no mercado atualmente, e neste caso, você vai ter problemas quando for para um navegador que não tem algum determinado recurso de CSS que você usou.

Ao trabalhar com Javascript (com ou sem jQuery, mas fica bem mais fácil fazer com ele), este problema é mitigado, uma vez que o javascript é capaz de alterar o DOM dinamicamente, e com isso inclusive detectar a resolução da tela em runtime e escolher as melhores configurações de CSS.

Entretanto não é nem 8 e nem 80. Fazer tudo no Javascript não é boa ideia, e fazer tudo no CSS também não deverá ser. É preciso ter um certo bom-senso para saber o que vai no CSS e o que vai no Javascript.

No caso de propriedades estáticas de classes e ids, o melhor é colocá-las no CSS. No Javascript, o máximo que você faz é adicionar ou retirar classes de elementos da árvore DOM.

No caso de propriedades que variam bastante, tais como animações de posição, tamanho, cor e formato de objetos, fazer isso no CSS resultaria em uma monstruosidade horrível de se trabalhar, se é que seria possível. Já no Javascript, você provavelmente colocaria algumas poucas linhas de código para dar um jeito nisso.

Enfim, você tem que saber em qual dos dois fica mais fácil, mais leve e mais natural de ser alterado. Não coloque tudo de um lado só e nem tudo no outro, coloque cada coisa no lado em que fica melhor, analisando caso-a-caso.

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta é um tanto quanto baseada em opinião mas vamos lá. Em minha resposta, vou fazer uma ponte com outras dúvidas suas apresentadas aqui no stackoverflow.

Quando você trabalha com o **css** para adicionar estilo, você acaba gerando uma praticidade para alterações pois, você mesmo ou qualquer outro programador consegue ter acesso simplificado via "inspecionar elemento", por exemplo.

Em tudo o que crio, tento ponderar o uso de **css** e **jquery** da seguinte forma:

- CSS: Crio o cenário inicial, atribuo as cores, tamanhos e posições.
- JSS: Trabalho com eventos, ou seja, crio pequenas funções que geram algum efeito visual ou completam a navegação, como por exemplo uma `nav` que fica fixa após chegar a um scroll X

Podemos fazer uma ponte para os frameworks e exemplificar um pouco melhor.
Normalmente o pessoal trabalha com [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) em sites e até mesmo sistemas web com aspecto mais vertical. Nele você tem componentes **css** e também **js** que trabalham de forma similar a descrita acima.

Temos também alguns frameworks com uma base maior no `javascript`, como é o caso do DHTMLX, que gera uma interface mais voltada a sistemas online e possui aspecto mais centralizado, sem tanto trabalho vertical, pensando na usabilidade do usuário. Nesse caso, temos poucas folhas de estilo e em geral, a maioria do trabalho feito via scripts pois você pode simplesmente arrastar as `div` ou até mesmo redimensionar, por exemplo.

Não há como falar que um método é totalmente certo e outro é totalmente errado, por isso a sua pergunta está prestes a ser fechada.

Um ponto que eu acho interessante bater é: Se você trabalha com uma estrutura baseada em geral na construção **css**, tente arrumar eventuais problemas de estilo pelo próprio **css** e *vice-versa*